# xceed datatgrid export to excel Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Export.ExcelExporter class is not found

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am trying to export a DataGrid's data to excel. I tried it using the xceed document (see the code below).

But there, I was not able to find `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Export.ExcelExporter`

```
public static void ExportToExcel(Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridControl dg, string File_Name)
{
    try
    {
       Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Export.ExcelExporter exporter = new ExcelExporter(dg);
        // All details
        exporter.DetailDepth = int.MaxValue;
        // Use the current system list separator
        exporter.FormatSettings.Separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator[0];
        exporter.Export("d:\\orders.csv");
        MessageBox.Show("Excel File has been Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install the xceed tools first? Did you include correctly the assemblies? Is this a compiler or a runtime error?

Comment: Installed  xceed tools,in Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Export i couldn't find a ExcelExporter class

Comment: So your application does not built at all. Is thats true, please edit you question an add this information also. In any case, try to be as detailed as possible in order to understand your issue

Comment: Please check a diagram.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you are having. I installed the package and the ExcelExporter is there. If you still need help, you can send us an email at support@xceed.com